# Very new to jquery and trying to get the text on my button to change when I click it

Tags: jquery, button

I'm extremely new to jQuery and I'm trying to get the text of my button to change when it's clicked.  For some reason it only changes after I click it twice.  I found an answer to something very similar to this on stack overflow but I couldn't adapt it to my needs. Possibly because this is so new to me I'm still trying to understand it. Here's what I have.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.more').click(function() {
            $(this).siblings('.more-text').slideToggle(500);
            if ( $(this).text() == 'Show more' ) {
                $(this).text('Show less');
            }
            else {
                $(this).text('Show more');
            }
        });
    });
```

Right now it only changes to 'Show less' if I click the button twice and the .more class is toggled closed.  How do I get it to say 'Show less' on the initial click? What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post relevant part of your HTML  as well?

Comment: $(selector).click is not really the recommended method for binding things these days. You should look at $(selector).on("click", function(){}) instead

Comment: Also, if the element with the '.more' is added after the click handler is bound, it won't work

Comment: @S.Buda There's nothing wrong with `.click()`. And if the element didn't exist, it wouldn't work on the second click either.

Comment: If what S.buda said is correct, then use $(parentSelector).on('click', selector, function(){...})

Comment: Here is the documentation for .on()    https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Pretty certain your button says "Show More" instead of "Show more" or some silly typo like that, making the initial equals check fail.  Instead of fixing that, though, I would suggest using data attributes to control and check for the state of the button.  See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/hr537qcp/1/

Answer (score 0):

first, you don't have to put your button click function inside document.ready.

and if you want to use class selector, you can use it like this

```
$(document).on("click", ".more", function() {
    $(this).siblings('.more-text').slideToggle(500);
        if ($(this).text() == 'Show more' ) {
            $(this).text('Show less');
        }
        else {
            $(this).text('Show more');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there was in fact nothing wrong with the jquery.  In my html the closing `</button>` tag was misspelled.  I fixed that and it worked. I then subsequently removed the `<button>` element and replaced it with a p element 
 with the same class and the toggle still works.  On the first click it shows the text and the text within the p element changes to 'Show less' on the first click and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

just try this one:

html

```
<button class="more">Show more</button>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.more').click(function() {
     $(this).siblings('.more-text').slideToggle(500);
     if ($(this).text() == 'Show more' ) {
            $(this).text('Show less');
     }
     else {
        $(this).text('Show more');
     }
  });
});
```

it should works, see this demo https://jsfiddle.net/hr537qcp/2/